# Error building custom Qt app examples from ParaView

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, paraview

I’m researching making a Qt-based desktop application to use Paraview framework and make a simpler ParaView GUI. The documentation says that there are some examples here

`https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/tree/master/Examples/CustomApplications`

In ParaView forum I read this

```
First, you need to build ParaView.

Then, choose one of the subfolder you points out: there all are independent examples. Build it in a new build directory. You will need to specify the path to the ParaView build directory in CMake with ParaView_DIR.
```

I build ParaView but I don't undestand this part `You will need to specify the path to the ParaView build directory in CMake with ParaView_DIR.`

Here is my structure

```
dev
  |- pv
  |    |- build
  |    |- paraview-superbuild
  |
  |
  |- qt-examples
       |- one
          |- build
          |- Clone1
```

How do I add the path?

I tried adding `set(ParaView_DIR /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/build)` at the beginning of `CMakeLists.txt` of Clone1 and then I executed `cmake ../Clone1` from the build folder.

But got the error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindParaView.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "ParaView",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ParaView" with any
  of the following names:

    ParaViewConfig.cmake
    paraview-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ParaView" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ParaView_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "ParaView" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Does the `ParaViewConfig.cmake` or `paraview-config.cmake` from the error message exist in `/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/build`?

Comment: cross posted from https://discourse.paraview.org/t/executing-custom-applications-examples/3015/5, where discussion is going on

Comment: You might have to do `make install` in your paraview build dir, and then pass the installation directory to cmake, like `cmake -DParaView_DIR=/path/to/paraview-install`

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message says all you need to do. You need to set the variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` pointing to the path of your build. This can be done in the cmake command line argument when building one of the examples:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/build
```

As you are trying to build Qt programs, you may want to set also the prefix path to your Qt libraries. [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) is a semicolon separated list of paths:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/build;/Users/username/Qt/5.12.5/gcc_64
```

Comment: I find cleaner using `<Project>_DIR` (or `<Project>_ROOT` since cmake 3.12, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/variable/PackageName_ROOT.html#variable:<PackageName>_ROOT) as suggested by the cmake output. `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is some kind of global variable that can have side effects .